# How to get a unique index for nested loops in Svelte Kit

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I'm creating a website for uploading images. You can create albums, and each album can contain a number of posts. There are numerous photos in each post (a array of images).

It looks like the following:

```
const albums = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Album 1',
    }
]

const posts = [
    {
        "album": 1,
        "images": [
            "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
            "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
        ],
        "author": 1,
    },
    {
        "album": 1,
        "images": [
            "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
        ],
        "author": 2,
    },
    {
        "album": 1,
        "images": [
            "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
            "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
            "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
            "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
            "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
        ],
        "author": 4,
    }
]
```

For each post image in the array, I need to obtain a distinct index number.
How I'm trying to obtain it in Svelte is as following:

```
{#each posts as post}
    {#each post.images as image, index}
        {index}: {image}
    {/each}
{/each}
```

However, this won't give me an unique index for every image. It will result in the following:

```
0: https://picsum.photos/200/300
1: https://picsum.photos/200/300
0: https://picsum.photos/200/300
0: https://picsum.photos/200/300
1: https://picsum.photos/200/300
2: https://picsum.photos/200/300
3: https://picsum.photos/200/300
4: https://picsum.photos/200/300
```

Except, I need it like this:

```
0: https://picsum.photos/200/300
1: https://picsum.photos/200/300
2: https://picsum.photos/200/300
3: https://picsum.photos/200/300
4: https://picsum.photos/200/300
5: https://picsum.photos/200/300
6: https://picsum.photos/200/300
7: https://picsum.photos/200/300
```

How would I be possible to achieve the above one?

One thought of mine would be reducing/mapping the array and creating a post object for each single image. However, I'm unsure how to achieve this.

Comment: `Please don't hate on me for posting this.` - apols if misinterpreting, but please don't assume the worst in us, we want to help you fix issues in your code, we'd never hate anyone for asking for help :)

Comment: (If you want to thank people, upvote answers and accept the one that was the most helpful to you.)

Comment: @H.B. Sadly I can't upvote yet since I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote. :[

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a "getter" function to get all the images from every post

```js
function getImages() {
    return posts.map(post => post.images).flat()
}
```

And use that instead of two nested `each` loops

```html
{#each getImages() as image, index}
    {index}: {image}
{/each}
```

Comment: I appreciate you responding. I later added this, however since a post can have an unique author, who I want to display, this wouldn't be working right..

Comment: @Wolf You just need to include the author in the mapping then, probably something like `posts.flatMap(p => p.images.map(i => ({ author: p.author, image: i })))` ([REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/2ca9f4bfbf8c417a8cd0c91b192be6ec?version=3.48.0))

Comment: @H.B. Thank you for your response! The code on your REPL worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Generate a nested array containing the desired numbers:

```html
<script>
  // const posts = ...

  $: numbers = buildNumbers(posts)

  function buildNumbers(posts) {
    let nr = 1
    const result = []
    posts.forEach((post, postIndex) => {
      post.images.forEach((image, imageIndex) => {
        result[postIndex] = result[postIndex] || []
        result[postIndex][imageIndex] = nr
        nr++
      })
    })
    return result
  }
</script>

<ul>
{#each posts as post, postIndex}
  {#each post.images as image, imageIndex}
    <li>{numbers[postIndex][imageIndex]}: {image}</li>
  {/each}
{/each}
</ul>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/fcdbd96647c94e338340a7cc5f321059?version=3.48.0)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use both indexes?

```html
<script>
  const posts = [
    {
      album: 1,
      images: ['https://picsum.photos/200/300', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300'],
      author: 1,
    },
    {
      album: 1,
      images: ['https://picsum.photos/200/300'],
      author: 2,
    },
    {
      album: 1,
      images: ['https://picsum.photos/200/300', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300'],
      author: 4,
    },
  ];
</script>

<ul>
  {#each posts as post, index}
    {@const postIndex = index}
    {#each post.images as _, index}
      {@const imageIndex = index}
      {@const uniqueId = `${postIndex}:${imageIndex}`}
      <li>{uniqueId}</li>
    {/each}
  {/each}
</ul>

<!--
0:0
0:1
1:0
2:0
2:1
-->
```